# PHP - Parsing Google Map Coordinates

Tags: php, google-maps, parsing, dom

I've been using PHP simple HTML dom parser to parse some data from websites.

Say if there is a web page with a Google map on it and that map has marker on it indicated by a lat and long coordinate, is there a way of retrieving those coordinates from a JavaScript variable?

Here is an example of the JavaScript code I would like to get access to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function GMinitialize()  {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.11, -11.11);
var mapOptions = { zoom: 16, center: myLatlng,   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  position: myLatlng,      map: map  });
}  ;
</script>
```

Comment: If it's always in the same format, you may be able to use a regex to filter it out. If it isn't, you'd have to intrpret the Javascript which is going to be very complex.

Comment: The format will always be the same, I just have no idea how to get at the JavaScript elements from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be exactly the same structure just with different coordinates, as you suggested in your comment above, you could pull the text of the `<script>` tag with PHP Simple HTML DOM, then parse out the coordinates passed to the LatLng contructor with a regex...perhaps something very simple like:

```
/var myLatlng = new google\.maps\.LatLng\((.*)\)/
```